# replace (change ids) in phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table in phpMyadmin which is called Circuits with a column MCBs_id and i want to change the id 22 with id 19, the id 23 with id 20 and the id 24 with id 20.

How can i Run a script to change all at once with SQL query?

Comment: please provide table structure , as well as sample data and desired output , is MCBs_id  primary key?

Comment: its not a primary key but a part of table, type is int, length is 11, default null and null ticket. desire output is to replace the above ids with the ones mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are the queries to update de value of field MCBs_id:

```
UPDATE Circuits SET MCBs_id = 19 WHERE MCBs_id = 22;
UPDATE Circuits SET MCBs_id = 20 WHERE MCBs_id = 23;
UPDATE Circuits SET MCBs_id = 20 WHERE MCBs_id = 24;
```

Consider that all the rows which meet the condition (WHERE) will be update in each of the queries.

Comment: after doing it it affected another column which was a drop down with a value, now i want to upload the old database and fix it as it was but when importing i get a #1050 - Table 'Circuits' already exists, how do i fix it

Comment: You can rename the Table 'Circuits' AS  'Circuits_old': ALTER TABLE Circuits
  RENAME TO Circuits_old;

Comment: #1022 - Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-15be1_70a510'

Comment: It seems that you have rows with the same primary key value. The primary key have to be unique in each row.

Comment: but the table was imported just fine.

Comment: Which is the table's primary key?

Comment: id is the primary key and secondary Meletes_id

Comment: when you said "id", did you mean MCBs_id? Check if the new table "Circuits" has all the rows. You can check if a field has a duplicate value with this query: SELECT field, count(\*) FROM table GROUP BY field HAVING count(\*) > 1;

Comment: Plain id 
2 errors were found during analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "table" at position 28)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "table" at position 28)

Comment: You have to replace table with the table name, and field with the field name.

Comment: i am not sure if i understand exactly what you mean, by the way all columns are there nothing is missing.

Comment: If MCBs_id is the primary key, so you can't have two rows with the same value (20) at this field, as you ask first. Don't forget to check if the table has all the rows. If everything is ok you can remove the table Circuits_old.

Comment: I refered to the data: if the table has all rows it had. Because you said at import throw error #1022.

Comment: i have 30000 rows!!! impossible to check. plain "id" is the primary key

Comment: You can check table for errors: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/check-table.html

Comment: Table 'beaut445_elculator.test_table' doesn't exis... but i think i dont need this test table, it might have been old

Answer (score 0):

then you need to do this :

```
;with cte as (
select Id , MCBs_id 
from yourtable 
where MCBs_id in ( 22,23,24)
)

update t 
Set MCBs_id = case cte.MCBs_id when 22 then 19 
                               when 23 then 20
                               when 24 then 20
from yourtable t
join cte 
 on t.Id = cte.Id
```

Comment: after doing it it affected another column which was a drop down with a value, now i want to upload the old database and fix it as it was but when importing i get a #1050 - Table 'Circuits' already exists, how do i fix it